# Can @dynamicMemberLookup be used to call methods?

Tags: swift, dynamic

In the documentation for `@dynamicMemberLookup` it says,

> Apply this attribute to a class, structure, enumeration, or protocol to enable members to be looked up by name at runtime.

If I'm not mistaken, instance methods are considered members of a struct / class. However, when I try to call a function dynamically I get an error saying:

> Dynamic key path member lookup cannot refer to instance method `foo()`

To reproduce the problem:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    
    func greet() {
        print("hello, my name is \(name)")
    }
}

@dynamicMemberLookup
struct Wrapper {
    var value: Person
    
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keypath: KeyPath<Person, T>) -> T {
        value[keyPath: keypath]
    }
}

let person = Person(name: "John Doe", age: 21)
let wrapper = Wrapper(value: person)

wrapper.greet()  // << Error: Dynamic key path member lookup cannot refer to instance method `greet()`
// Or
let function = wrapper.greet  // << Error: Dynamic key path member lookup cannot refer to instance method `greet()`
function()
```

How can I dynamically call `greet()` using `@dynamicMemberLookup`? Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can cobble it together by combining it with the `callAsFunction` feature. In your dynamic member lookup subscript, you return a struct whose callAsFunction body has the behaviour you want

Comment: @Alexander Would this work if I had more than one function I wanted to dynamically call?

Comment: You can return one of several different closures, either directly, or wrapped in a struct whose callAsFunction body invokes the closure

Comment: Ahh I didn't notice this is using the KeyPath variant of it. There's no automatic way to wire it up in the same way as with properties. With the more dynamic/unsafe string-based dynamic-member lookup, you could switch over the string and return one method reference or another, but you have to write that code by hand

Answer (score 3):

No, `dynamicMemberLookup` does not work for methods. As the signature of the subscript suggests, it only works for things that can be represented as a `KeyPath`. Method calls cannot be part of a key path. :(

> #### [Key-Path Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563)
>
> A key-path expression refers to a property or subscript of a type.
>
> The path consists of property names, subscripts, optional-chaining
> expressions, and forced unwrapping expressions. Each of these key-path
> components can be repeated as many times as needed, in any order.
>
> At compile time, a key-path expression is replaced by an instance of
> the `KeyPath` class.

I suspect the reason why it is called "dynamic *member* lookup" is because it also works with subscripts. The alternative of `dynamicPropertyOrSubscriptLookup` is rather a mouthful isn't it?

One rather hacky fix would be to change `greet` into a computed property:

```
var greet: () -> Void { {
    print("hello, my name is \(name)")
} }
```

If `greet` has had parameters, you could also change it into a subscript, but I think that is an even uglier solution.